# Is there a comprehensive list of Windows 7 Embedded Package Dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, windows-embedded-7

I am creating a new Windows Embedded 7 image and I am at the stage of selecting packages to include in the image.  In the process, I am trying to disable some bloated, annoying packages (Application Security, which includes UAC for example).

However once I click "Resolve Dependences" (excluding optional dependencies), Application Security gets rechecked.

My ultimate goal is to identify the package that depends on Application Security and kill it with fire.

Is there a 100% comprehensive list of package dependencies so I can quickly scan through it, identify which packages I want to exclude, and remove the necessary dependencies?  I have looked through the help files but they did not help.

Comment: I found that Group Policy Management is the dependency.  Too bad I can't get rid of that.

Comment: I gave up and installed the trial Windows 7 Toolkit.  It has a searchable help file with information on dependencies.